# Getting ObtainStyledAttributes to work properly in xamarin for Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, controls

I'm building a custom control in **Xamarin.Android** and as part of the initialization of that control I'm want to read the specified height for the control.

I'd like to use `ObtainStyledAttributes` because it gives me a way to convert string dimensions to dimensions easily.

So I call:

```
 context.ObtainStyledAttributes(attrs, new int [] { problemhere })
```

The issue I'm having is I don't know how to specify the constant for `layout_height` (this is the parameter I am looking to extract).  When I looked into the **Xamarin** documentation it states that there is a `Resource.Attribute.LayoutWidth` const defined, but I can't reference it in my source code.

I know I can also use `getAttributeValue()` to get as a string, but then it doesn't convert.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the `Android` OS level resources:

```
int[] attrsArray = { 
    Android.Resource.Attribute.LayoutWidth,
    Android.Resource.Attribute.LayoutHeight 
};
var typedArray = context.ObtainStyledAttributes( attrsArray);
var layout_width = typedArray.GetDimensionPixelSize(0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
var layout_height = typedArray.GetDimensionPixelSize(1, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
```

Comment: Thanks!  Just what I needed.